# Error creating IAM Role : MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am looking to create an IAM role that would be able to access to s3 service using the following syntax:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_s3_fullAccess" {
  name               = "prod_ec2_s3_fullAccess"
  path               = "/"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.s3_access.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ec2_s3_fullAccess.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.s3_access.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ec2-read-only-policy-attachment" {
    role = "${aws_iam_role.ec2_iam_role.name}"
    policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess"
}
```

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_access" {
  statement {
    sid = "SidToOverride"
    actions   = ["s3:*"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "s3_access" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
}
```

However, I get the following error message:

Error creating IAM Role prod_ec2_s3_fullAccess: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
│       status code: 400, request id: dddb80c9-77a1-4ac3-b54a-4fab751f11db
│
│   with module.usersgroups.aws_iam_role.ec2_s3_fullAccess,
│   on ..\modules\iam\resources.tf line 88, in resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_s3_fullAccess":
│   88: resource "aws_iam_role" "ec2_s3_fullAccess" {

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/59646356/2291321. Basically you've confused the assume role policy (allowing things to use the role) with the policy document (what the role is then allowed to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `assume_role_policy` should tell who/what can assume the role, not what the actual permissions after assuming it are. Such policies don't have `resources`. So it should be:

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_access" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    sid = ""
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

      principals {
        type        = "Service"
        identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
      }
  }
}
```

In your case, you want an ec2 instances to be able to assume the role, I guess.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I was confuse with assume_role_policy and now it's clear and working as per your suggestion.